# load more data on scroll to top in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I trying to load more data on scroll to top recyclerview Like Whatsapp chat .
my adapter is contain multiple views 
I loading few rows from sqlite to display in recyclerview and load more data when scroll the top.
when i load the more data the app is crashed

```
02-20 22:57:01.324 6833-6833/ E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: , PID: 6833
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at .adapters.PrivateChatAdapter$ViewHodler.setSenderMsg(PrivateChatAdapter.java:208)
    at .adapters.PrivateChatAdapter.onBindViewHolder(PrivateChatAdapter.java:124)
    at .adapters.PrivateChatAdapter.onBindViewHolder(PrivateChatAdapter.java:46)
```

the linearlayoutmanger is         `linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);`

```
0     <---- i want to load the new data here
1
2    
3
4    
5
6
```

When i add the new data to arraylist

```
arrayMsgs.add(0, new PrivateMsg.Builder(PrivateMsg.LOADING_MORE_MSG, 0, true).build());
privateChatAdapter.notifyItemInserted(0);
```

The old item in position 0 is repeated

Comment: after adding data to list, you can notify adapter by  calling `privateChatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: I've notified the adapter with changed But the problem lies in views<br>
Before update arraylist .. the position zero is contain message view<br>
but when i update the position zero with progress bar and notify the adapter with changed he is not update the view and stay message view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the issue by resetting the adapter as below :

```
recyclerview.setAdapter(privateChatAdapter);
```

after adding data to position zero in arraylist
Maybe because the views item stored in cache of the recyclerview